# Structure array assigning

Tags: arrays, matlab, data-structures, cell-array, xlsread

I have a 1x5 structure array called `Game` with two fields i.e.

```
Game(5) = struct(Points, Scorers);
```

Now, I also have a cell-array (5x2 cell array) (imported from `xlsread` - so its all in cell-array form).

```
pts = [1 2;3 4;5 6;7 8;9 10];
```

How should I go about assigning each row of `pts`, to each of the 5 structures in `Game`, respectively?

For example: `Game(3).Points` should be row `3` of `pts` (which is `[5 6]`).

`Game(2).Points` should be `[3 4]`. `Game(1).Points` will be `[1 2]`.

Comment: The default behavior of `xlsread` is to return numeric data in matrix form.  How did you end up with a cell array?

Comment: file='abc.xlsx'; [pts pts pts]=xlsread(file) where pts is a 5x2 cell (matlab workspace). My actual import cell array has both num & txt. in my Qs above I just made up a very simple 5x2 cell from 1:10.

Comment: Oh, there's your problem.  In Matlab, asking a function to return `[pts pts pts]` rather than `[a, b, c]` will sequentially overwrite the return variable assignment, leaving you with only the `c` portion of the output.  In this case, the third output `c` is formatted as a cell array. Just use `pts = xlsread(file)` to get the numeric data in matrix form. I'll give an answer below on how to put that into a structure.

Comment: oh sorry I didn't mention. I have both numeric and txt values. will I still import a cell array? I'd prefer a matrix  - easier to index and manipulate

Comment: Well, depending on how the spreadsheet is formatted, you may be able to use something like `[pts, scorers] = xlsread(file)` to return a matrix `pts` with numeric values and a cell array `scorers` with string cells.

Comment: Ooh now I have a type double numeric array thanks!. I just need to know if you need a 'for loop' to solve my main issue

Comment: You don't have to use a `for` loop.  I gave you a more compact one-line solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your worksheet is organized such that rows correspond to observations and columns correspond to variables - e.g. points (numeric) and scorers (string) - you can import the data into Matlab using:

```
[pts, scr] = xlsread(file);
```

Then you can simply read the matrix `pts` and cell array `scr` into each field of a structure array as:

```
Game = struct('Points', num2cell(pts,2), 'Scorers', scr);
```

This takes advantage of [`struct()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html)'s built-in ability to match output dimensions to its inputs, avoiding the use of a `for` loop to iteratively assign imported values to the fields.

Comment: This worked! Later I just had to reshape pts from column cell to row (horizontal) cell so it's compatible with structure 'Game'. also I didn't know what the dim '2' in num2cell accomplishes, but that's ok.